# Картинка перекрывает выпадающее меню

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Всем привет, при использовании плагина jekyll-paginate-v2 у меня не работает вот этот кусочек кода, а именно где идет присвоение класса "selected" этот каласс вообще не присваивается, в описании плагина сказано

```
The trail object exposes three properties:

num: The number of the page
path: The path to the page
title: The title of the page
```

[Описание работы этого момента внизу страницы](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/blob/master/README-GENERATOR.md)
Та же самая проблема в самом примере от разработчиков этого плагина.
Нужно выделить активную страницу в пагинации.
[Пример от разработчиков](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/tree/master/examples/03-tags)

Нужно прописать jekyll build и jekyll serve.

```
{% if paginator.page_trail %}
    {% for trail in paginator.page_trail %}
      <li {% if page.url == trail.path %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
          <a href="{{ trail.path | prepend: site.baseurl | replace: '//', '/' }}" title="{{trail.title}}">{{ trail.num }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: И что? Она не выделяется? Или выделяется, но не так, как вы ожидаете?

Comment: Он вообще не присваивается =(

Comment: А вы выведите пути куда-нибудь в атрибуты. Может, они и правда разные?

Comment: Ликвида не знаю и не могу с ним работать=(

Comment: Так самое время [его изучить](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers). Это дело недолгое.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что руби плохо дружит с виндовс, перейдя на линукс такой проблемы не было

Comment: **https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3404/199934**. Спасибо.